# Choose the correct option

Tags: number-theory, integers

I had a question in one of my tests, but I don't think explanation provided was correct. Here is the question:

[image]

I think $q$ can be greater than $p$, and in that case $r=p$. Did I interpret the question incorrectly?

Comment: The question states that the integers are distinct, so $p\neq r$.

Comment: Note that the final statement implies three of the previous ones, so if it is true, so are the others.